# Jquery ajaxForm() doesn't fire 'success' although it works successfully

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, ajaxform

Today I was trying to send files via Ajax request using the JQuery AjaxForm plugin. However, it doesn't fire the success function as it uploads the file without any javascript run time or compile time error.

Here is my code:

```
<table id="haberresmiekle">
<form action="action.asp?kmt=resimyukle" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="haberresmiekleform">
<tr>
    <td><input type="file" name="file"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input id="b" type="submit" value="Gonder"></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

and

```
<script> 
$("#haberresmiekle").dialog({autoOpen:false,title:"Resim Yukle"});
        var options={
                target:"#haberresmiekle",
                success:function(){alert('x');$("#haberresimekle").dialog('close');}
            };
        $("#haberresmiekleform").ajaxForm(options); 
$("#b").button();
</script>
```

**Thanks for any help**

**Note: It has been resolved.**

Comment: try this 'success':function(resutl){alert('im success');console.debug(result);}

Comment: What is it supposed to do? I didn't get any different action. The problem is doesn't go to that function at all

Comment: are you sure 'result' is not undefined?

Comment: if it was undefined and the success was fired. Then it would alert 'undefined'. The problem is that success is not fired.

Comment: every thing is fine. use firebug's net panel to see the response.

Comment: i use google chrome to see the response, thanks. And server returns exactly what i want it to return.

Comment: @exculuber let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1021/discussion-between-mls-and-exculuber)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yor script will do nothing(except in IE) as long as you dont use valid selectors.

```
$(haberresmiekleform)-> $('#haberresmiekleform')
$(haberresmiekle)    -> $('#haberresmiekle')
$(button)            -> $('#button')
```